# Capture skype for Business Events

Tags: skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I am developing an windows form application, which should get triggered as soon as call is picked up from **Skype for Business**.

I was wondering is there any event available which i can listen to when a call is picked up **Skype for Business.**